# How is clickView used properly?

Tags: android, testing, junit

I'm trying to write a simple test app to run in JUnit. I've been having trouble getting clickView to click on the proper view. Below is some sample code that can be used on SkeletonActivity sample app that comes with the SDK.

```
    public class SkeletonInstrumentation extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity>{

 private Activity act;
 private  Button bClear;
 private  Button bBack;
 private  EditText eMain;

 public SkeletonInstrumentation(){
  super("com.example.android.skeletonapp", Activity.class);

 }

 public void setUp() {

  String app = this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getPackageName();  
  this.setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);
  act = this.launchActivity(app, SkeletonActivity.class, Bundle.EMPTY);

  bClear = (Button) act.findViewById(R.id.clear);
  bBack = (Button) act.findViewById(R.id.back);
  eMain = (EditText) act.findViewById(R.id.editor);


 }

 public void testClick() 
 {

  TouchUtils.clickView(this, bClear);


 }

 public void testSendKeys() 
 { 

  act.runOnUiThread(
    new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
      bClear.clearFocus();
      eMain.requestFocus();
     }
    }
   );

  this.sendKeys("A B C D E F G ENTER");
 }

}
```

testClick runs, but clicks on the main EditText view that has focus when the Activity starts and ends up bringing up the on-screen keyboard. I want it to click on the 'Clear' button below the EditText. Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the min and max target SDK in the AndroidManifest.xml worked for me; I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4442252/2544267).  In the project that is being tested (not the test project) I added the following line to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17" android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
```

and all of my uses of TouchUtils started behaving consistently again.

I had the same problem [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436383/) and while I was able to find a workaround but it became really cumbersome so I spent more hours getting to the bottom of it.

Answer (score -1):

The use of clickView here is correct. The problem was in the AndroidManifest.xml. Min and Target SDK must be set for it to work properly.