# TouchUtils clickView clicks the wrong view

Tags: android, android-testing

I am trying to use `TouchUtils.clickView()` to navigate to another screen in my app's tests.  The call to `clickView` always clicks the wrong View:

```java
public void navigateToWorkout(int i) {
    mMonitor = mWorkout.setMonitor(mInstrumentation);
    final LinearLayout clickme = (LinearLayout) mWorkouts.getChildAt(i);
    pc.runOnUiThread(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                clickme.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            }
        }
    );
    try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (Exception e) {}
    TouchUtils.clickView(MyApplicationTest.this, clickme);
    mWorkout.getFromMonitor(mMonitor);
}
```

It turns the correct item (`LinearLayout`) in the `ListView` cyan and then half a second later the call to `clickView` generates a click event on the `EditText` that has focus (indicated by a visible flash in the `EditText`).

If I simply click on the newly CYANed `ListView` item in the emulator the test starts working again until the next time it tries to navigate to another screen by clicking on a `ListView` item.  Then, again, it clicks on the `EditText` with focus and gets stuck unless I click on the item manually.

This hasn't worked since I imported this project onto my new laptop from my old desktop where it had worked for months.  I wish I could compare the two side by side but the old desktop died a horrible death which prompted my switch to a laptop for development.

I could provide more code for the `OnClick` handler or the view I am trying to call but the app works if I just add a few clicks by hand; all of my trouble is with the test.  I am quite stuck on trying to make this work and am willing to try any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the min and max target SDK in the AndroidManifest.xml worked for me; I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4442252/2544267) (which [I elaborated on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20366776/2544267)).  In the project that is being tested (not the test project) I added the following line to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17" android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
```

and all of my uses of TouchUtils started behaving consistently again; no more annoying workaround!